# Create own Google Translate API call

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, google-translation-api

I try to call the Google Translate API but always get a 403 error that I didn't provide a valid API key.

I did create one, though, on my Google Cloud Platforms website here: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials

Here's what I'm doing:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)

my_text <- c("Hallo Mama", "Ja älskar dig")
my_key <- "MYKEY"

textbody <- toJSON(list(q = my_text,
                        target = "en"))

translated <- POST(url = paste0("https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2"),
                   add_headers("key" = my_key),
                   content_type("application/json"),
                   body = textbody,
                   encode = "json")
```

But this returns said 403 error, i.e.:

```
fromJSON(rawToChar(translated$content))
```

gives:

```
$error
$error$code
[1] 403

$error$message
[1] "The request is missing a valid API key."

$error$errors
                                  message domain    reason
1 The request is missing a valid API key. global forbidden

$error$status
[1] "PERMISSION_DENIED"
```

Note: the "MYKEY" used above I have of course replaced with my created true API key.

Any ideas what's going on?

---

Update: the following does work for v2 of the API (but not v3). I was missing te unboxing in the JSON body and I seem to have to put the APIkey into the URL:

```
textbody <- toJSON(list(q = my_text,
                        target = "en"),
                   auto_unbox = TRUE)

translated <- POST(url = paste0("https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=", my_key),
                   content_type("application/json"),
                   body = textbody,
                   encode = "json")
```

Comment: Have you completed [all the steps listed here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/setup) - creating a project, enabling billing, enabling the translate api for your project, etc.?

Comment: Apparently not. Thanks for sending the link. I don't have connected it to some billing information, because I assumed there would be a free version unless you translate too many responses. Since I'm using a corporate account, I guess I need to reach out to my admins first to link my project to our billing information.

Comment: I think a few years ago GCP switched things so that you need to enable billing for many of their APIs, even if you stay in the free tier. So some older tutorials don't mention that, but it's a requirement. I had a similar thing using the directions API.

Comment: Yes, I see where this is coming from. So you need to provide payment details , even if staying in the free zone. Once you exceed that threshold you get automatically charged. I've seen that in other commercial APIs as well. It just didn't occur to me that I need to do this active linking to our billing account of the company. So let's see what the admin says and if that solves the issue. At least gets me one step further for now.

Comment: @GregorThomas so I finally setup the billing information, but still get the 403 error. I also tried to use the v3 API, which looks a bit different in the URL, but this also didn't work (because it then complained about a required OAuth athentication).

Comment: ok, got it working now with the v2 of the API, but not with v3 where it complains about OAuth stuff (although I have a valid APi key).